# --disable-web-security no longer works after Chrome / Canary update

Tags: google-chrome, auto-update

I've started getting the following error after a [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) update.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:65068/initialize*** . Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

If I revert back to an older version of chrome it works fine.
Version 48.0.2564.116 was working fine (but may have cached my preflight headers)

Version is 49.0.2623.87 stopped working.

I can call the GET directly and there is no error.  (Double click error in chrome network tab)

My api does have Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *

All instances of chrome were killed before trying.

Is there a new web security setting I need to use to test locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security check behavior did change recently from version 48 to 49 of Chrome.
Reference this support item on Google forums: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9nHBcjNW384

For debugging purposes, you can get Chrome to run without the security checks using these command-line switches together:

--disable-web-security --user-data-dir